# Odd Characters in Ruby Cron Output

Tags: ruby, cron

I have some `Ruby` scripts that I run overnight.  They output to a `cronlog.txt` as a report I can check daily.  This is using the `puts` method.  It has some characters output which don't show up in the terminal when run.

How can I rid these odd characters?  I am assuming I need to force some kind of formatting.
Here's a sample of the output:

```
[H[2J[0;31;49m### wobbly/assign_city_pc.rb 2020_Sep_01 3:09[0m
[0;33;49mlocations count: 16484[0m
[0;33;49mgrabbed count: 150[0m
[0;33;49mtargets count: 16334[0m
```

Desired output:

```
### wobbly/assign_city_pc.rb 2020_Sep_01 3:09
locations count: 16484
grabbed count: 150
targets count: 16334
```

Comment: What odd characters do you want to get rid of? And can you show your ruby code about ```puts```?

Comment: Oh, thought that was obvious.  `[H[2J[0;31;49m`, `[0m`, `[0;33;49m`.  I will edit the post.

Comment: @Rich_F those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for formatting in color terminals.

Comment: @Stefan I see.  Markup.  Should have known that.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

As per @Stefan, `ANSI escape codes`.

I took out the gem 'colorize' from that script.

Now, as @Stefan properly noted, it was the resulting codes that gave the characters in my situation.  There are other gems that also could do this, but I haven't used them.  I don't know what their names are.  I don't wish to use them.  I will not research them.  I am assuming there are others that accomplish this.  I'm also thinking there are other gems that provide other markup as well.  I haven't used them.  I don't wish to use them.

None of the aforementioned gems I will research in order to post a novel about new markup.  I used one, and I stopped using it and the characters went away.  I can safely assume that this specific change is what brought on the fix.

As you can see, I am assuming that some gems providing "ANSI escape codes" would be a sufficient answer to this question, as it was evident more characters were being added.  My original point was to say "I took out anything that generated more characters", but that wasn't good enough.

So the answer to the specific characters I had, was to take out `colorize` only.  Any other new characters generated are outside of my knowledge and I will not be testing any further on something that was kindly answered by three words.

Comment: @spickerman does that suffice?   Need I explain how I removed a gem?

Comment: @Rich_F maybe list the gems you removed?

Comment: It did answer the question.  Read my new full description.  You've completely missed the point.  This is not about one gem.